# How do I theme links in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, theming

I am building a VSCode theme.
Currently im trying to change the behaviour for links, but I can't find the right setting. In my current theme file, there is no statement in `tokenColors` that seems to change anything. There is also no `fontStyle: "underline"` or something similar, yet a link like `http://www.google.com` is underlined.

I looked at it with the built in developer inspector `(Developer: Inspect TM Scopes)`, but it only says:
`string.quoted.docstring.multi.python
source.python`

Where does the underline setting come from? How do I change the format for links?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of underlined links:

1. Link parsed from grammars. These would have a `foo.link.language` type scope
2. Links detected by a link detector

For links in the grammar, you can theme the link scope as normal.

You cannot directly theme links that come from the link detector. The `"editorLink.activeForeground"` ui theme property lets you theme the link when it is active, but you cannot theme a non-active link if it does not have a grammar scope associated with it.

For python specifically, the grammar likely need to be updated to parse the links. This can be done either by modifying the grammar or with an [injection grammar](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1751)